# angularjs without controller ng-click not firing

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am practising angularjs. In below example, ng-click is not firing at all, not sure why. I actually not using any controller in my code, may be because of that, ng-click not firing?

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp1">

<div ng-init="users=[{name: 'john', city: 'NY', order: 10},{name: 'james', city: 'washington', order: 20},{name: 'william', city: 'seattle', order: 30}]">

<h2>Customers</h2>

Search Customer: <input type="text" ng-model="searchText" placeholder="search customer here">

    <br><br>
    <table border="2">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th ng-click="orderByProperty('name')">Name</th>
                <th ng-click="orderByProperty('city')">City</th>
                <th ng-click="orderByProperty('order')">Order</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="user in users | filter : searchText | orderBy : orderByProperty : true">
                <td>{{user.name | uppercase}}</td>
                <td>{{user.city}}</td>
                <td>{{user.order | currency}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
var myApp1 = angular.module('myApp1',[])

function orderByProperty(propertyName){
    // alert('dsfdf')
    return propertyName;
}
```

Please tell me what went wrong in above code? Is that mandatory to use controller in a code? If not used, ng-click do not work at all?

**UPDATE**
When I replaced `ng-click` with '`onclick`', even is getting fired, but sorting functionality is not working.

**UPDATE2: BELOW IS THE UPDATED CODE**

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp1">


<div ng-controller="MyController">

    <div ng-init="users=[{name: 'john', city: 'NY', order: 10},{name: 'james', city: 'washington', order: 20},{name: 'william', city: 'seattle', order: 30}]">

    <h2>Customers</h2>

    Search Customer: <input type="text" ng-model="searchText" placeholder="search customer here">

        <br><br>
        <table border="2">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th ng-click="orderByProperty('name')">Name</th>
                    <th ng-click="orderByProperty('city')">City</th>
                    <th ng-click="orderByProperty('order')">Order</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="user in users | filter : searchText | orderBy : orderByProperty : true">
                    <td>{{user.name | uppercase}}</td>
                    <td>{{user.city}}</td>
                    <td>{{user.order | currency}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
var myApp1 = angular.module('myApp1',[])

myApp1.controller('MyController', ['$scope', function($scope){

    $scope. orderByProperty = function(propertyName){
        // alert('dsfdf')
        return propertyName;
    }   

}])
```

Above I used controller, now evenT gets firing but sorting not working as expected..

Comment: Bind the **orderByProperty** function with the `$scope` then only you can access methods defined in javascript from your HTML. `$scope acts as a glue between view and controller`. So, anything that you want to access from view , bind it to $scope or $rootScope.

Comment: onclick is an html functionality, not angular

Answer (score 2):

Yes you need to have the **`ng-controller`** placed in order to get **`ng-click`** work.

> When a controller is attached to the DOM via the ng-controller
>   directive, Angular will instantiate a new controller object, using the
>   specified controller's constructor function. A new child scope will be
>   available as an injectable parameter to the controller's constructor
>   function as $scope.

Read more on **[`controller`](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller)**

Comment: But in above example, i really do not need any controller since its just only one page, right? So, is that not possible to make ng-click work without ng-controller? And I also heard ng-click will have its own scope..

Comment: I just updated in my original post, please look into it.

Comment: @John onclick will work because its the javascript way.

Answer (score 0):

As @Sajeetharan said, in angularjs all functions you call need to be declared in controllers, that is how it works

Comment: I just updated in my original post, please look into it.

Answer (score 0):

before using `ng-click` u must place `ng-controller` in your HTML.

> `<body ng-app="myApp1" ng-controller="myAppCtrl">`

```
var myApp1 = angular.module('myApp1',[]);

myApp1.controller('myAppCtrl',['$scope',function ($scope) {

$scope.orderByProperty=function(propertyName){
    // alert('dsfdf')
    return propertyName;
}
}]);
```

Comment: I just updated in my original post, please look into it.

Answer (score 0):

To make it work, 2 places need to change:
Binding orderBy with a ng-model value.

```js
var myApp1 = angular.module('myApp1',[])

myApp1.controller('MyController', ['$scope', function($scope){

    $scope. orderByProperty = function(propertyName){
        $scope.myorder = propertyName;
    }   

}])
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp1">


<div ng-controller="MyController">

    <div ng-init="users=[{name: 'john', city: 'NY', order: 10},{name: 'james', city: 'washington', order: 20},{name: 'william', city: 'seattle', order: 30}]">

    <h2>Customers</h2>

    Search Customer: <input type="text" ng-model="searchText" placeholder="search customer here">

        <br><br>
        <table border="2">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th ng-click="orderByProperty('name')">Name</th>
                    <th ng-click="orderByProperty('city')">City</th>
                    <th ng-click="orderByProperty('order')">Order</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="user in users | filter : searchText | orderBy : myorder : true">
                    <td>{{user.name | uppercase}}</td>
                    <td>{{user.city}}</td>
                    <td>{{user.order | currency}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```